# How to redirect route in Nuxt/Vue and recall the mounted hook?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

newbie Nuxt question:

I try to redirect to the same route with a different param, and have no idea how to use $nuxt to push the route so I tried the below vue router.

The url is changed but mounted hook does not get invoked to change the data

```
methods: {    
  changeMatch(event) {
 
  this.$router.push({
    name: "tran-dau-id-tuong-thuat",
    params: { id: event.target.value },
  });
},
```

Update: I follow https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

```
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      if (to.params.id != from.params.id) {
        this.loadFixture();
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Try out `updated` hook instead of `mounted`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim does not work because it's the same route, so the component will be reused, hence, no lifecycle hooks get invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You have to watch the router param for changes.

```
watch: {
  id(newId) {
    // has changed call mounted logic again ...
    this.getDataAgainLogic(newId) ... 
  }
}
```

Vue Router [Documentation: Reacting to Params Changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)